# How to find $x$ in $\log_9 (x)+\log_9 (x-2)=\log_9 (8)$

Tags: logarithms

How would I go about solving this problem? I know that you can remove the $\log$s if the have the same base resulting leaving $x(x-2)=8$, but what would be the next step to finding the value of $x$?

Comment: Do you mean $\log_9$ not $\log9$?

Comment: The equation is just a quadratic! You have $$x^2-2x-8=(x-4)(x+2)=0$$ and just remember that $x>2$.

Comment: I think the exercise meant $\log_9$ instead of $\log 9$, doesn't seems like you can go on "adding basis to the logarithm" as you said. If that's the case you can proceed like those answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x(x-2) = 8$ if we distribute, $x^2 - 2x = 8$, or $x^2-2x-8 = 0$. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$x(x-2)=8$$
$$x^2-2x=8$$
$$x^2-2x-8=0$$
$$(x-4)(x+2)=0$$

But as you can see we want $x>0 $ and $x-2>0$   because of the domain of $\log x $ is $x>0$

Thus $x>2$

Thus $x=4$ is the only solution to this equation